# Inaccurate Angles

Tags: c#, xna

In my game engine, I wrote a script to check if a point is within 4 points (A square polygon). This is done by calculating the angles of each point to the point we are checking (As the total of the 4 angles should always equal to 360 if it is within the polygon). However it fails completely. I have concluded after debugging that the scripts are inaccurate but I can not see what I have done wrong. Can someone tell me why these functions are screwing up? I am at a complete loss as what is going wrong.

```
public static float getAngle(Vector2 position1, Vector2 position2)
{
    float radians = (float)Math.Atan2(position1.Y - position2.Y, position1.X - position2.X);
    return Math.Abs(radians * 180 / (float)Math.PI);
}

public static bool inSquarePolygon(Vector2 target, Vector2 pointA, Vector2 pointB, Vector2 pointC, Vector2 pointD)
{
    float pointAAngle = MathMethods.getAngle(pointA, target);
    float pointBAngle = MathMethods.getAngle(pointB, target);
    float pointCAngle = MathMethods.getAngle(pointC, target);
    float pointDAngle = MathMethods.getAngle(pointD, target);

    if (Math.Round(pointAAngle + pointBAngle + pointCAngle + pointDAngle) == 360)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("SUCCESS");
         return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Find a case that fails.  Write down on a piece of paper what you believe the result should be of every line in your method. Now step through your method in the debugger running that test case, and write down what every line actually does. When the two lists are different, that's where the bug is.

Comment: I did this and sat down and calculated the angles. My conclusion is that the problem is in the getAngle function.

Comment: The calculations the computer makes are close, but not perfect 360. It ranges from 350 to 370

Comment: Correct. It is now way off. I think I am going to just start from scratch. Again...

Answer (score 0):

here is a visual aid to show that your current `getAngle()` values overlap:

[image]

---

Here is a possible workaround that does what the 2nd graphic indicates while working within your current methodology

```
if (Math.Round(pointAAngle +
                (pointBAngle - pointAAngle) +
                (pointCAngle - pointBAngle) +
                (pointDAngle - pointCAngle) +
                (360 - pointDAngle)) == 360)
{
    //success
}
```

Comment: Your math says "if 360 + a - a + b - b + c - c + d - d == 360" -- under what circumstances do you expect that to be false?

Answer (score 0):

I found the bug. There was nothing wrong with my getAngle function. It was unfinished. However I did go back into my old university files after sleeping on it and found the code I needed.

```
float corner1 = ((pointD.X - target.X) * (pointA.Y - target.Y)) - ((pointA.X - target.X) * (pointD.Y - target.Y));
float corner2 = ((pointA.X - target.X) * (pointB.Y - target.Y)) - ((pointB.X - target.X) * (pointA.Y - target.Y));
float corner3 = ((pointB.X - target.X) * (pointC.Y - target.Y)) - ((pointC.X - target.X) * (pointB.Y - target.Y));
float corner4 = ((pointC.X - target.X) * (pointD.Y - target.Y)) - ((pointD.X - target.X) * (pointC.Y - target.Y));

return (Math.Sign(corner1) == Math.Sign(corner2)) && (Math.Sign(corner2) == Math.Sign(corner3)) && (Math.Sign(corner3) == Math.Sign(corner4));
```